# Separate functions in python?

Tags: python

I'm not sure if function is the word I am looking for. In fact I don't really know what I'm saying but I have some code and it's not quite doing it what I want to. Basically I want to copy and paste this code I've got and email it to someone. I want them to be able to simply copy and paste it into their Terminal and perform calculations.:

```
## SCSAC.py

def round(x, base=5):
    return int(base * round(float(x)/base))

option = 'yes'
while (option == 'yes'):
    x=float(raw_input('How many accumulated orders do you have from retailers: '));
    y=float(raw_input('How many units are in the inventory: '));
    z=float(raw_input('How many accumulated orders have you placed: '));
    print 'Place an order of %s units' % round(((x / 25 + y / 10 + z / 25) + 115));
    print ; 
    option=raw_input("Do you wish to calculate another order? (Enter 'yes' to continue or any other key to quit):: ");
    print
```

Whenever I type this code in line for line, it works perfectly. That's because there are basically 3 seperate things happening here.

1. I define "round" which rounds a value to the nearest 5.
2. I define an option to loop the program upon completion
3. I define the actual program, and in that I round the answer and conclude with the option to loop. You may notice 2 `print`'s that don't print anything, but they are only there to have blank lines.

When I copy and paste it, I get a syntax error.
I am not a programmer and I have just been playing with this all day. I just want to know how I can edit this code so it is copy/paste-able and will run the way it is supposed to.

Comment: Please include the exact syntax error you get, full traceback.

Comment: You need to do a copy paste in chunks.. You cannot do all that code at once.. You will get syntax error..

Comment: I get "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" and it highlights "option". It will just take the first word after the first function and consider that the syntax error. I suppose I will have to just include instructions to copy and paste in chunks

Comment: The error I get attempting to run that code is `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`, because your round function calls itself, but doesn't have a base case. It looks like the intention is to use the built-in `round()` function internally, but the builtin is no longer available, since you overrode it with a custom function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [IPython](http://ipython.org/) instead of the regular Python interpret at the shell. With IPython, you can type `%cpaste`, and then paste a whole chunk of code, which it will execute for you step by step, saving the intermediate variables into working memory.

If you insist on pasting it in the regular interpreter, then do it line by line, and take special care for the indentations. The indentations are usually where paste syntax errors come from.

Even better, use [Emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/). Then you can just save the pasted code into a file, like `test.py`, type `M-x shell`, and then `python test.py` to quickly run it. Or, if you saved it to a file like `test.py` then in IPython you can also type `%run "test.py"` and it will run the code and again store intermediate variables into working memory.

If you're copy/pasting this after making changes more than once or twice, just save it to a file and run it like a script.

Comment: Okay this is going to sound astronomically stupid, but I've been trying to figure out how to save a code as a script and then run that script? How exactly do I save it as a script and then run it?

Comment: @Tyler. Save it `.py` extension... And then to run it.. in command prompt, go to the folder where you saved it, and type `python test.py`... Where `test.py` is the name of your file..

Comment: That's OK. Don't worry if the question is elementary... it is *not* stupid and it's better to ask and learn. With Python it's very straight-forward. Just open a text editor of some sort, and type your code there (making sure to respect the indentation syntax in Python). Save that file (let's say you save it as "my_file.py"). Then at a command prompt just type `python my_file.py`. Hopefully you're working on a Linux machine, otherwise you may want to look at the Cygwin shell for Windows. If any of this command prompt stuff sounds hard, just search for and/or ask another question about it.

Comment: And that question is not stupid at all.. Every one starts from scratch sometime.. And you learn more by asking more questions and getting them resolved. Always get your problem solved, no matter how small you think it is..

Comment: Okay thanks guys, I slowly but surely figured it out. I was able to get it to work in Terminal by going to the directory where it was located and typing `python scsac.py` and it loaded up. Great help!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can save the code in a file, and run it using Python.
You can add `#!/usr/bin/env python` to the beginning of the file, so it can run on *nix systems (if you have execute permission).

Or, you can do `python SCSAC.py` and run your code. This works on all systems (AFAIK). You can email the file to your person, and she can run it using Python. This seems to be the easiest way to do it.